# no puedo loguearme con autentificacion manual de laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    protected $table='administrador';
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    protected function Login(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::attempt(["email"=>$request->get('email'),"password"=>$request->get('password')])){
            return Redirect::to('home');
        } else{

        }
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'administracion/reportes/general';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Cuando intento cambiar la tabla para autenticación, aparecen problemas.

He detectado que attempt retorna verdadero, al momento de direccionar la pagina me devuelve al login no se porque,Cuando deberia enviarme al home.

Este el código de home controller

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Esta Es la RUTA

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Si estás tan molesto con Laravel, simplemente no lo uses.

Comment: Que otro framework me recomiendas......

Comment: He utilizado unos 8 frameworks de php y no he encontrado uno más sencillo y práctico que Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cambiar de tabla para la autenticación, debes hacerlo en el modelo que tengas asignado en la config/auth.php, el cual es por defecto app\User.php. La tabla le pertenece al modelo, no al controlador, pues el controlador no tiene nada que ver (normalmente) con la base de datos.

app\User.php

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table='administrador';
    public $timestamps=false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Esa corrección ya la hice la tabla es tomada en cuenta, pero te dire algo muy raro, si ingreso con una credencial incorrecta , me salta un error diciéndome que no encontró el usuario, si lo pongo bien no tira el error pero me devuelve siempre al login, entonces en el controlador de Home  le quite el constructor que tenia al middleware auth y listo me direcciona a la pagina de inicio,pero al hacer Auth::check() me lanza false

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución cambie los  constructores en los controladores 
Antes tenía algo así dentro del constructor $this->middleware('auth')

Ahora lo cambie a $this->middleware('auto.basic')

Ya functiona mi login y retro a true en la vista no me regresa de nuevo al login, el error consiste en los guards laravel ya trabaja con un provider en específico y su guard por defecto en el trait del login al modificarlo se pierden métodos que se encargan de establecer el guard.